# SQL syntax error for my java program

Tags: java, mysql, syntax, xampp

My code :

```
try{ Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/lentele", "root", "");
String select = "SELECT * FROM darbuotojai WHERE 1";

    String ID = infoID.getText();
    String Vardas = infoV.getText();
    String Pavardė = infoP.getText();
    String Pareigos = infoPar.getSelectedItem().toString();
    String Alga = infoAlg.getText();
    String Premija = infoPre.getText();

    String insert = "INSERT INTO `darbuotojai`(`ID`, `Vardas`, `Pavardė`, `Pareigos`, `Alga`, `Premija`) VALUES ('"+ID+"','"+Vardas+"','"+Pavardė+"','"+Pareigos+"','"+Alga+"','"+Premija+"',)";


        stm.executeUpdate(insert);
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Užklausa sėkminga");
        infoID.setText("");
        infoV.setText("");
        infoP.setText("");
        infoPar.setSelectedItem("");
        infoAlg.setText("");
        infoPre.setText("");

        display();
    } catch (Exception e) {JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e.getMessage()); }
```

And i get errors like this:

```
you have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near ')' at line 1.
And ones more: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: Access denied for user ''@'localhost' to database 'lentele'.
```

Please, explain these problems for beginner in the easiest way.
This code is for the add button, which would help to insert info into my table.

Comment: remove the last `,` in `'"+Premija+"',`

Answer (score 1):

Remove the comma before your closing bracket:

```
Premija+"',)";
```

becomes

```
Premija+"')";
```

Except don't build your query by hand, unless you want to be vulnerable to SQL injection attacks: use a [`PreparedStatement`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html).